# How to use LWP with client cert and CA

Tags: perl, ssl, curl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I curenttly have some perl code which drops out to shell to call curl to talk to an end point with certificates. this works fine but i always feel like i am cheating in perl when i escape to shell and take the easy option. below is the curl command i am using and this works fine.

$soap_response = `echo '$soap_request' | curl --cacert $self->{'server_cert'} --cert $self->{'client_cert'} -d '\@-' -H 'SOAPAction:urn:anonOutInOp' $self->{'end_point'} -s | xmllint -format -`;

I have a CA file, and a client file, both in PEM format.

I have tried to use LWP and Net::SSL to make this communication purely in perl and get rid of the reliance on curl but i cannot for the life of me get it to work.

I set up the enviroment for Net:SSL as

```
#set up the ssl envrioment for Net::SSL
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = $client_cert;
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}   = $server_cert;
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR}    = $certificate_dir;
```

then send my request as

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $endpoint);
$request->header(SOAPAction => '"query"');
$request->content($query);
$request->content_type("text/xml; charset=utf-8");

my $response = $ua->request($request);
print $response->content,"\n";
```

The output i get when running is

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:HTTP</faultcode><faultstring>(403)Forbidden</faultstring><detail><ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">hh0pgw01</ns2:hostname><ns3:HttpErrorCode xmlns:ns3="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">403</ns3:HttpErrorCode></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

so it seems like its exchanged the CA file and is happy with the host however my request is then being rejected with 403 forbiden error, which i suspect is to do with my client key not being exchanged properly with the request.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue or suggest where it may be falling down.

Answer (score 1):

> so it seems like its exchanged the CA file and is happy with the host however my request is then being rejected with 403 forbiden error, which i suspect is to do with my client key not being exchanged properly with the request.

It looks like the client sent a certificate and the server accepted it. Because otherwise the SSL handshake would have failed and in this case the server would not be able to send a 403 or even some XML back. Thus it might be that the server side application does not associate the necessary rights with the certificate you have send, i.e. this is the wrong certificate or the server got misconfigured.

It might also be that your request is wrong. When looking at the curl and LWP request it looks for me like you are sending different headers relating to SOAP.

Apart from that it looks like you are using a very old version of LWP or explicitly force the use of the deprecated and insecure Net::SSL/Crypt::SSL backend. Current versions of LWP (version>=6.0, i.e. everything within the last 4 years) don't use Net::SSL/Crypt::SSLeay but instead use [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-Socket-SSL/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pod) as backend. To configure this use `ssl_opts` and then the relevant SSL options as documented for IO::Socket::SSL:

```
 LWP::UserAgent->new(..., ssl_opts => {
      SSL_ca_path   => ... # directory with CA, if file use SSL_ca_file
      SSL_cert_file => ... # the client site certificate
      SSL_cert_key  => ... # the key for the client site certificate
 });
```

Comment: I have versio 6.05 of LWP, but I kept getting handshake error when using ssl_opts. The certificates are correct as when i run them using curl it works. I have also tried changing the soap header and it makes no difference

Comment: According to the debug output with Net::SSL the site uses SSL 3.0 only, which is disabled by IO::Socket::SSL by default since 10/2015 because of the POODLE attack. You can explicitly enforce it with `SSL_version => 'SSLv3'` in `ssl_opts`. Apart from that look at the server side for log messages why the server considers your certificate not usable for authorization.